# $_POST return false with isset()

Tags: php, forms

I have a form set up with this attribute in it: enctype="multipart/form-data" and when I jump to the PHP part and check if the $_POST vars exist trough the isset() function, they retun false after totally checking the form.
This doesn't happen at all when not using the enctype attribute

Didn't found any solution on either Google or Stack overflow, so decided to make my own post.

Form:

```
   <form action="../processingShit/register.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
     <div id="obligatory_inputs" class="col s12">
       <div class="input-field col s6" id="fName_wrapper">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
      <input id="input-fName" value="something" name="fName" type="text" class="validate" maxlength="20">
      <label for="input-fName">Nombre</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6" id="sName_wrapper">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
      <input id="input-sName" value="something" name="sName" type="text" class="validate" maxlength="20">
      <label for="input-sName">Apellido</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col s6 input_wrappers">
      <div class="input-field col s12" id="userName_wrapper">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
        <input type="text" id="input-userName" value="something" name="userName" class="validate">
        <label for="input-userName">Nombre de usuario</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div  class="col s6 input_wrappers">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
     <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
     <input id="input-email" value="something" name="email" type="email" class="validate">
     <label for="input-email">E-mail</label>
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s6 input_wrappers">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
        <input type="password" id="input-password" value="something" name="password" class="validate">
        <label for="input-password">Contraseña</label>
        <span id="security_label">Nivel de seguridad: <span id="security_show" style="color: grey;"><b><i>?</i></b></span> </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s6 input_wrappers">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
        <input type="password" id="input-password2" value="something" name="password2" class="validate">
        <label for="input-password2">Repetir Contraseña</label>
        <span id="matchPW"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
     <div id="opcional_inputs" class="col s12">
       <center><div style="width: 90% !important;">
         <div class="input-field col s12">
             <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
             <textarea id="prDesc_ta" value="something" name="prDesc" class="materialize-textarea" maxlength="150"></textarea>
             <label for="prDesc_ta">Descripción de perfil</label>
           </div>
           <br>
           <br>
       <div class="input-field file-field">
         <div class="btn grey darken-4">
           <span>Archivo</span>
           <input type="file" value="something" name="prPic">
         </div>
         <div class="file-path-wrapper">
           <input class="file-path" type="text" placeholder="Imagen de perfil">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="input-field file-field">
         <div class="btn grey darken-4">
           <span>Archivo</span>
           <input type="file" value="something" name="prPort">
         </div>
         <div class="file-path-wrapper">
           <input class="file-path" type="text" placeholder="Portada de Perfil">
         </div>
       </div>
     </div></center>
     </div >
     <center>
     <button id="sendFormBTN" class=" grey darken-4" type="submit">
       REGISTRARSE
     </button>
     </center>
   </div>
 </form>
```

register.php :

```
  <?php
       //returns false   
 if (isset($_POST["fName"]) &&
     isset($_POST["sName"])  &&
     isset($_POST["userName"])  &&
     isset($_POST["email"])  &&
     isset($_POST["password"])  &&
     isset($_POST["password2"])  &&
     isset($_POST["prDesc"])  &&
     isset($_POST["prPic"])  &&
     isset($_POST["prPort"])
       ) {

          //my code

}

    ?>
```

Some of the code is in spanish by the way, it shouldn't affect how you understand it.

Thanks for the patience :\

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186002/discussion-on-question-by-joseph-fernandez-post-return-false-with-isset).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see what the problem is, after posting your real code.

It's for this:

```
<input type="file" value="something" name="prPic">
```

and `$_POST["prPic"]`

When handling files, you need to use `$_FILES` and not `$_POST`.

Error reporting would have shown you an undefined index notice.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Seeing that you're not uploading files, just remove that input and the associated `isset($_POST["prPic"])` conditional.

However, if you plan on handling file uploads, you're going to need to learn how to do this with the following reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Which would be out of scope of the question.

---

Edit:

> I'm more like looking of an error that would for some reason make the $_POST VARs not exist if you use the enctype attribute in the form tag – Joseph Fernandez

It returned true when not using the enctype since there was an input of the same name, just not the right associated superglobal. (Taken from [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992793/post-return-false-with-isset/53992942#comment94823658_53992793)).

Comment: well... thanks, and sorry for the unclearness of the OP

Comment: @JosephFernandez No hard feelings. It seems that being patient paid off ;-) I hope you've learned something here and it happens so don't worry about it. You responded to comments asking for your real code and you did, so thanks for that. I found your question rather interesting after your asking the "reason", so I gave your question an upvote for it. Remember next time though; post your real code :-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a submit button too within the form. addition to that you are missing value attribute here. you should specify a value to the input control to check with isset.

```
    <form action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="username" value="some value" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: You only need to include a value if you are setting a default value.

Comment: No i don't have to.

Comment: How does this solve the question or add anything?

Comment: A submit is important.  The OP omitted it and it is unclear whether there is a submit in their code.  This answer may help clarify or solve the problem.

Comment: @user2182349 [I already did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992793/post-return-false-with-isset#comment94823362_53992793) and before the answer, a lot earlier I might add. You should read the other comments under question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner haven't seen that. anyways +1 to you.

Comment: @MahipatVadher Thanks. Yeah, this one was impossible to answer with what was originally posted, since nobody knew what it was we we're really dealing with. And now we know.